# Android Implement zoom of multiple images in a Framelayout?

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

In a Framelayout, i have several images. Like a Small markers Image on a big image map in the back.

I am trying to implement a zoom and  i was able to implement zoom on one ImageView but rest of the images are not getting zoom In proportionally and position of small images (Marker image) gets affected due to zoom In.

The position of the rest of images should also be zoom in/move with respect to its previous position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by merging all your Bitmap on a canvas, that will make one Bitmap as a combination of all bitmap. once canvas is ready just connect it to ImageView.

Bitmap drawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1280, 720, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);

canvas.drawBitmap(, null, , new Paint());

mapImageView.setImageBitmap(drawnBitmap);